# how to use python to get multiple values in a row?

Tags: python

ex.
data:

```
Test done Tj=59 Tach=2506, P=108  V=0.7 G=1365.0  at Tue June 7 22:47:33
```

in truth，it's some irregular delimiter in the row
And i want to get the following result:

```
Tj = 59\n Tach = 2506\n P = 108\n G = 1365\n Time = 2022-06-07 22:47:33
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the main things you need to achieve your desired output. You can tweak any of the parameters to better fit your data:

```
from datetime import datetime

a = 'Test done Tj=59 Tach=2506, P=108 V=0.7 G=1365.0 at Tue June 7 22:47:33'

# Get time after 'at '
time = a.split('at ')[1]

# Replace ' ' with '\n' in data and strip ','
b = a[len('Test done '):-len(time) - 3].replace(' ', '\n').replace(',', '')

# Load datetime string
datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(time, '%a %B %d %H:%M:%S').replace(year=2022)

# Final result
result = f'{b}Time = {datetime_obj}'
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for your special answer,and I don't understand this part（len('Test done '):-len(time) - 3），because i want to remove the comma after（Tach=2506 ，），but.replace({' ': '\n', ',': ''}) inoperative

Comment: Hi @buger. Forgot about the comma, I have updated the response to remove comma after Tach=2506,. The above syntax is to select data between 'Test done ' and time info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**regular expression**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) :

```
line = 'Test done Tj=59 Tach=2506, P=108  V=0.7 G=1365.0  at Tue June 7 22:47:33'

import re

match = re.search(
        r'Tj=(?P<Tj>[\d.]+)[\s,]+'
        r'Tach=(?P<Tach>[\d.]+)[\s,]+'
        r'P=(?P<P>[\d.]+)[\s,]+' 
        r'V=(?P<V>[\d.]+)[\s,]+' 
        r'G=(?P<G>[\d.]+)[\s,]+' 
        r'at (?P<Time>.+?)$', line)
        
# [\d.]+ => match numeric (0-9) and dot (.)
# [\s,]+ => match spaces or commas (,)

if match:
   print( match.groupdict() )
else:
   print( 'no match' )
```

Output:

```
{'Tj': '59', 'Tach': '2506', 'P': '108', 'V': '0.7', 'G': '1365.0', 'Time': 'Tue June 7 22:47:33'}
```

Then :

```
print('\n'.join(f'{a[0]} = {a[1]}' for a in match.groupdict().items()))
```

Output :

```
Tj = 59
Tach = 2506
P = 108
V = 0.7
G = 1365.0
Time = Tue June 7 22:47:33
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your way is what I want,but I need new line after each data，i have try add "\n" in print() and It is useless